# Converting KML file to layer on existing map in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, kml

I have a map in arcGIS, and i want some kml data to be shown over that map. But if i convert kml to layer, the data is not visible on that map. Both the layers can be seen separately by "zoom to layer" option but not simultaneously.

Even if the map itself is converted from KML file, the other data when i convert goes to somewhere else and does not show over that map (Though that was over the map in Google earth)

Answer (score 2):

As Sercan says this sounds an awful lot like coordinate systems not lining up properly. When you zoom to the separate layers are you ending up with stupid scale readings?

[image: crazy scale!]

If so you probably haven't set up the correct transformations and coordinate systems.

Comment: No the scale looks quite fine. Though both the layers have different scales for visibility

Answer (score 1):

What kind of projection systems do you use for your layers? I think your layers have different projection systems.

Comment: I did not specify any coordinate system, but its GCS_WGS_1984  by default for the whole data frame. And even i try to transform it to any other system but no gain.I also tried the same extent for both the layers but it didn't work too.